# C# SQL connection string variable?

Tags: c#, sql, variables, connection-string

In C# WinForms, where should I put my SQL connection string variable if I want to access it all over my application?

Right now I'm copy-pasting it wherever I'm using it.

```
//Sql connection string

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + globalvariables.hosttxt + "," + globalvariables.porttxt + "\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ha;Persist Security Info=false; UID='" + globalvariables.user + "' ; PWD='" + globalvariables.psw + "'");
SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the app.config (or web.config) for that. It has a special section for connection-strings. [See the MSDN-article about that.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx) Then you can retrieve the string in code as use1515791 has already pointed out, like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOfConnectionStringInConfig"].ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 1):

I rather not using app.config file, because it's not secure and hackable easily (every connection info is stored in plain text format here).

If I'm not using any of my DLLs, I place the SqlConnection in Program.cs with public getter and disabled setter. I make all the initializations in Program.cs, so it looks something like this:

```
static class Program
    {
        private static SqlConnection con;
        internal static SqlConnection Con
        {
            get
            {
                return con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + globalvariables.hosttxt + "," + globalvariables.porttxt + "\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ha;Persist Security Info=false; UID='" + globalvariables.user + "' ; PWD='" + globalvariables.psw + "'");
            }
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

Now can access it (for example) from you Form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = Program.Con;
        }
    }
```

I've created a DLL to connect to SQL easily, check it [here](https://www.csharp-tutorial.hu/downloads/sql-connection-methods-dll/) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a rather general question imo.. depends on the application structure and so on. I tend to use a class "ApplicationContext" with properties for such things. However, maybe

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["whatever"].ConnectionString
```

is used a lot i think (add reference to System.Configuration)

Btw, if you use it "all over the place", don't you need an adapter class instead?

EDIT

```
public class DataAcces
{
    private string Connectionstr;
    public DataAcces()
    {
        this.Connectionstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["whatever"].ConnectionString;
    }
    public object ReturnSomething()
    {
         using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(this.Connectionstr))
         {
         //do stuff to db and return something
         }
    }
 }
```

and then when you need it

```
....
{
    var whatYouNeed = (new DataAcces()).ReturnSomething();
}
```

typos happen :) this is the easiest to use i can come up with, not the best.

Comment: I have 3 Forms that all use sql queries which requires a connectionstring.

Comment: When you say adapter class, do you mean creating a global connectionstring. Like some of my string already has "globalvariables" ?

Comment: No, i mean a class thats responsable for all data access. So that all sql is defined in that class.

Comment: But how do you call the connection class inside a void ?

Comment: I know that I can make a public void and call et from another void like this: sqlcount(sender, e); But I dont think this can be used as a connectionstring variable.

Comment: Ofcourse there are a lot other constructions possible, but the most simple is just

Comment: (cant edit above it seems) Updated my answer with a SIMPLE example